# in python i want to return none instead of empty string

Tags: python-2.7

i want to return none but that gives me an error 
i do not want to return empty strings

```
def read_line2(self, timeout=None):  ## Read Radio2 Serial line
        try:
            return self._rq2.get(block=timeout, timeout=timeout)
        except Empty:
            return ''
```

Comment: How do you let it return `None`? What is the caller?

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: This code snippet is not complete. It does not show where the error appears. Could you please add more details? Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In python to return None, you just `return None`.

```
def returns_none():
    return None


x = returns_none()
assert x is None
```

I think your issue has to do with `except Empty:`. Is Empty a custom exception that you have defined, because it isn't a python built-in.

Comment: except Empty: is an exception when the Queue is empty. right now its returning empty lines in the printer which i dont want